# YUI DataTable using KnockoutJS bindings

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, yui, yui-datatable

I have an example working at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BM3kX/5).

It has a piece of JSON consumed by a YUI DataTable which I need to create using KnockoutJS bindings. I'm fairly new to KnockoutJS and would like to know how this can be done.

The table should be created under the markup -

```
<div class="yui3-skin-sam" id="datatable"></div>​
```

The code goes as below -

```
YUI().use('datatable', 'datasource-local', 'datasource-jsonschema',function(Y){
var data  = {"generations": [{
    "type": "Modern",
    "showName": "The Modern Generation",
    "imgURI": "file:/D:/projectGen.png",
    "relations": {
        "father": {
            "age": "49",
            "firstName": "George",
            "lastName": "Mathews",
            "priority": "1",
            "profession": "Service"
        },
        "mother": {
            "age": "47",
            "firstName": "Susan",
            "lastName": "Aldrin",
            "priority": "2",
            "profession": "Home-Maker"
        },
        "brother": {
            "age": "28",
            "firstName": "Martin",
            "lastName": "Mathews J",
            "priority": "3",
            "profession": "Engineer"
        },
        "sister": {
            "age": "23",
            "firstName": "Laura",
            "lastName": "Mathews J",
            "priority": "4",
            "profession": "Fashion Model"
        },
        "aunt": {
            "age": "50",
            "firstName": "Sally",
            "lastName": "Bekkers",
            "priority": "5",
            "profession": "Singer"                
        }
    }
 }]
};
var localDataSource = new Y.DataSource.Local({source:data});
var dynamicColumns = Y.Object.keys(data.generations[0].relations);
var config = {
    schema: {
        resultListLocator: 'generations',
        resultFields: [{key:'showName'}]
    }
};

Y.Array.each(dynamicColumns,function(key){
    config.schema.resultFields.push({
        key: key,
        locator: "relations."+key + ".firstName" 
    });
});

var jsonSchema = localDataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, config);
console.log(config.schema.resultFields); 
var table = new Y.DataTable({
    columns: config.schema.resultFields
});

table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, {
    datasource: localDataSource
});

table.render('#datatable');
table.datasource.load();
```

});
​

Can this be done using KnockoutJS bidings? I know that an HTML table can be created well using KnockoutJS bindings but I find the YUI part tricky. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom binding helps resolve this problem. I can put the datatable creation code in the custom binding so that it will create he table on the markup from which the binding was called. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to add some data-bind attributes to your table cells. YUI table allows you to customize the TD element creation through the use of templates. Take a look at [the YUI documentation for more information on this](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.BodyView.html#property_CELL_TEMPLATE)

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Knockout bindings? How about using the  'html' binding to this problem?

I read the YUI documentation you suggested but it seems kind of not applicable in the problem's context.

Comment: What do you mean "Using knockout bindings"? Isn't that what data-bind attributes are for?